# How to estimate the complexity of sequential algorithm given that we know the complexity of each step?

Tags: time-complexity

First case:
I was stumble upon a two step sequential algorithm where the big O complexity of each step is $O(N^9)$.

Second case:
Also if the algorithm have three steps where the complexity of step 1 is $O(N^2)$, the complexity of step 2 is $O(N^3)$ and the complexity of step 3 is $O(N^9)$

What would be the complexity of the first case and second case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, we have $O(n^9)+O(n^9)$ and according to [it's summation properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties) we have $O(n^9)+O(n^9)=O(2n^9)=O(n^9)$.

For the second case, both $n^2$ and $n^3$ are smaller than $n^9$, so we have $O(n^2)+O(n^3)+O(n^9)=O(n^2+n^3+n^9)<O(n^9+n^9+n^9)=O(3n^9)=O(n^9)$

In the general case, if we have time complexities $t_1,t_2,...,t_k$, then $O(t_1)+...+O(t_k)=O(max\{t_1,...,t_k\})$

Comment: Thank you very much !
in the first case, if I can reduce the complexity of the second step to O(N^2) is it worth doing that since the complexity would be O(N^9) anyway ?

Comment: In terms of complexity analysis its no different. In terms of actual running time - it will be an improvement, and the speedup will depend on the constants behind the $O(n^9)$ and the $O(n^2)$.

Comment: If you have changed a $0.00001n^9$ to a $999999999n^2$ then obviously thats not really an improvement